# Django save value of select field in template

Tags: jquery, django

I am rather new to Django and am having trouble saving a value.

```
<td><select id="comp_sel">
 {% for company in companylist %}
  {% if user.company == company.name %}
   <option value="{{ company.name }}" selected>{{ company.name }}</option>
  {% else %}
   <option value="{{ company.name }}">{{ company.name }}</option>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</select></td>
```

I would like save the value that the user selects.

I know how to use jQuery to check when the user changes the select box, but can you please tell how to tell Django to save the selected value?

Thank you,
Michaela

Comment: In my opinion you should try create this without js. It'll be easier to understand Django :) next you can think about js.

Answer (score 0):

put a name attribute on the select element!  e.g.

```
<form action="{% url your_profile_url %}  method="POST">
    ...
    <td><select id="comp_sel" name="company">
    ...
```

...then you'll be able to get it in your view, and then save it in your model!

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        user.company = request.REQUEST['company']
        user.save()            
        ...
    else:      # it's a GET, so just display the form
        ...

    return render_to_response(...)       # etc etc
```